# How to convert nested dictionary into pandas dataframe with multi-index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, nested

I am trying to create a multi-indexed dataframe from a nested dictionary. However, while converting it to the DF, I am getting NaN values.

Below is the code that I have used to convert the dictionary to the DF.

- What I want is to have two sub_columns **Destination** and **Product_Revenue** (under one column) and **User_1** and **User_2** as index and all the **Dest_**  should relate **Purchase_** based on the users.

e.g. In Index:  User_1:

Row:

Dest_1 -  Milan - 234

Dest_2 -  London - 434

```
data = ({'Destination': {'User_1': {'Dest_1': 'Milan', 'Dest_2': 'London', 'Dest_3': 'Vienna', 'Dest_4': 'Milan', 'Dest_5': 'New Delhi'},
                         'User_2': {'Dest_1': 'Porto', 'Dest_2': 'Lisbon', 'Dest_3': 'Lisbon', 'Dest_4': 'London', 'Dest_5': 'Lisbon'}},

         'Product_Revenue': 
                        {'User_1': {'Purchase_1': 234, 'Purchase_2': 434, 'Purchase_3': 242, 'Purchase_4': 243, 'Purchase_5': 232}, 

                         'User_2':  {'Purchase_1': 542, 'Purchase_2': 332, 'Purchase_3': 135, 'Purchase_4': 524, 'Purchase_5': 232}}
})
```

To convert the dictionary to Dataframe,

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): data[i][j] 
                           for i in data.keys() 
                           for j in data[i].keys()},
                       orient='index')
```

Any help please?

Comment: @coldspeed  also, how can I make **User_IDs** as index and **Destination** and **Product_Revenue** as column? Can you please let me know how can I create sub-column with **Dest_** and **Purchase_**?

Comment: I am really sorry, but just now I took a closer look at your answer. It's interesting however not what I wanted. My bad for yesterday.

Comment: @coldspeed Done. Please have a look. Please let me know if I need to make anything clearer.